# custom allocator using move for vector of thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, move-semantics, move-constructor

I'm currently learning about concurrency in C++ and came across using a vector of threads, which I believe will be possible in C++0x. However, my current compiler doesn't appear to have an implementation of move-aware containers and so I get errors generated because `std::thread::thread(const std::thread&)` is deleted, ie I can only use the move constructor/move assignment with `std::thread`.

Am I correct in thinking I could circumvent this issue by writing a custom allocator using

```
void MyAllocator::construct (pointer p, reference val)
/* should be non-const reference to val because using move constructor? */
{
    new ((void*)p) T (std::move(val));
}
```

rather than

```
void allocator::construct (pointer p, const_reference val)
{
    new ((void*)p) T (val);
}
```

? Or some other variation on this theme (possibly using an overload of MyAllocator::construct).

NB: This is mainly intended to be a short-term educational exercise and well enough performing work around to play around with threads in containers. I'd only be using `MyAllocator` in this context. However, please also point me at any libraries that may have this implemented so I can have a poke around the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compiler doesn't provide a move-aware `std::vector` then you'll have to write your own specialization of `std::vector<std::thread>` rather than just provide a custom allocator. The whole C++03 `vector` interface relies on copying: `push_back()` copies elements in; `resize()` initializes the empty elements with a **copy** of the element passed as the second parameter (even if that is the default value of `T()`); `resize()`, `reserve()`, `insert()`, `erase()` and `push_back()` will **copy** elements if the vector needs reallocating, or elements otherwise need moving around, and so forth.

This is such a common problem that I've included such a specialization with my (commercial) [just::thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk) implementation of `std::thread`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to circumvent the problem would be to allocate the threads on the heap and manipulate pointers to them.

Check the `Boost Pointer Container` library: `boost::ptr_vector<std::thread>` seems to me what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement that std containers only take copyable objects has more to do with the C++03 container interfaces than it does with the allocator implementation. 
For example

```
vector<T> b(100);
vector<T> a;
a=b;
assert(a==b);
```

The standard assures us a==b is true. However, if T were not copyable, then in the best case a=b will not compile, in the worst a=b is undefined. Furthermore,

```
a.push_back(T());
```

may cause a to allocate new space, and under the hood there are copies made to the new underlying storage from the old.

Furthermore, there is nothing in the C++03 standard that says an implementation actually has to call allocator.construct, and in fact many (gcc for example) do not.

The C++0x standard adds new member functions to the container interface for moveable types, and clarifies how things like operator= behave in their presence.

See www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2486.pdf